# Moving cursor using code and opening folder

Tags: c++

This is a very random and maybe a bit strange question that i thought of at 3AM. I was thinking about how code could make my day to day life easier. Every morning I wake up, open chrome to the facebook conversations with my boyfriend, and write "good morning". And thats when i thought about this hypothetical project(just out of curiosity, I wouldn't use it haha): making a code that i can just run that does all of this for me.

I could have a html file that could redirect to the facebook link(https://www.facebook.com/messages/t/boyfriend_name). But how would I go on to make the code open this file, then move the mouse to where its supposed to go (the white area where the user inputs the text) then insert the text then press send?

I'm not asking for any code help as I can imagine that is too much, but my question is: could this be achievable in C++?(This is what we've been studying at school so far). If not, what coding language should I use? Is the idea achievable without a vast knowledge in computer science? If yes, have you got any sources about opening files using C++, moving cursor etc.

Note:The OS this would happen on is Windows 10

Comment: Yes, it is possible from C++, but it would be much easier with an existing automation tool such as [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/). Use the right tool for the job, and your life will be easier.

Comment: Or even easier, perhaps, use [Messenger API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/) to skip clicking altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do what you want is possible by using [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) and to use it from C++ you can try [AutoITX for C++](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/60107-using-autoitx-in-visual-c-and-dev-c/). With AutoIT it's possible to detect windows, move the mouse and insert text, although a web page is like a blackbox to it, so you'll have to rely on relative pixel coordinates (it might not be very robust).